# compiling error during runtime for class that compiles fine

Tags: future, permission-sets, compile-error

I'm getting the following error (below) while executing a future call. The mentioned class compiles and saves fine upon retesting. Any idea why this would be occurring at runtime? It seems to work correctly if i change the below method to simply return true and remove all other content.

```
 Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:\nhelper_formtemplate: line 144, column 54: sObject type 'PermissionSet' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE","fields":[]
```

The offending method:

```
public static Boolean checkCreateTriggerPermissions() {
           // determine if current user has permissions
    List<PermissionSetAssignment> permSetAssignments = [SELECT Id,Assignee.Id 
                                                        FROM PermissionSetAssignment
                                                        WHERE PermissionSetId 
                                                        IN (SELECT Id 
                                                            FROM PermissionSet
                                                            WHERE PermissionsAuthorApex=true
                                                            AND PermissionsAPIEnabled=true)
                                                        AND Assignee.Id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];

    // if the user has permission return true, otherwise false
    if (permSetAssignments.size() > 0) 
        return true;
    else 
        return false;

}
```

UPDATE: after digging a little deeper into the code, this error is actually coming from a tooling API request to create an Apex Trigger.

1. A trigger launches the process
2. It then does the check as described above to verify permissions
3. It then calls a future method which calls out to the Tooling API (v36) to generate a new Apex Trigger passing along the session ID
4. The failure response from trigger creation contains the error above

Other notes: Even with the permission set query code commented out I still get the same error, only if its actually removed does it work correctly.

Comment: This is probably a versioning issue. Make sure that no classes, triggers, pages, or components in your system are older than 22.0. If it is, I'll add an answer, if not, then at least we've eliminated a possible suspect.

Comment: @sfdcfox I checked all the files in the stack trace already but I'll check everything and report back.

Comment: @sfdcfox went through classes,triggers,vf pages,components, couldnt find anything older than 28 and updated them all to at least 31. Still seeing the issue.

Comment: @sfdcfox I added some more info in the original question that may be helpful

Comment: So...the code you posted is completely irrelevant and it's all about the callout to the `Tooling API`. Can you [edit] your post to include just code that is relevant to the core issue?